# WilkenSotenBuchtung

Tags: meaning, vocabulary

Lately these words WilkenSotenBuchtung and Stardenburdenhardenbart are trending in social media.
By researching on other sources, it seems like Stardenburdenhardenbart is not the actual word agreed upon by native speakers.But ,WilkenSotenBuchtung seems to be acceptable.

WilkenSotenBuchtung= to turn on all traffic lights green.

I am wondering what is the word for turning these all lights to red or orange?

Comment: While these words may look like they are German, they are gibberish as already said. People could easily create words that look like one certain language. Take for example *Brathering* which looks like an English word but is a German one.

Comment: related: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1481/what-does-stackenblochen-mean

Comment: Where are these words trending, exactly? There's a company Wilken that produces bookkeeping software. When I read your words first I thought you meant *Buchung* and not *Buchtung* and you are refering to their product.

Comment: Then, there's: https://www.quora.com/What-does-stardenburdenhardenbart-mean-in-German

Comment: @BernhardDöbler Yes, I first read it on social media German group. Some pages or online classes sharing it then I searched and could only find this quora link. That's the reason, I thought of asking it here. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry to be blunt here - *neither* is even remotely close to a German word and the possible individual words in this “compound” aren’t either. **They are just gibberish.**

The WilkenSotenBuchtung also has capital letters in the middle of the word, which standard German doesn’t (except company or product names that purposely break grammar rules , e.g. “BahnCard”, or compounds where the individual parts are separated by a hyphen, e.g. *Hals-Nasen-Ohren-Arzt*).

There is no specific word that describes “to turn traffic lights [any color]”, you have to express that via a  description like in English.